# Get the window title or name of the user

Tags: pidgin

I am trying to write a plugin for Pidgin, and stuck at a roadblock. I want to get the name of the user or the title of the window (because the default source code of Pidgin puts the name of the user in the title). Any pointers as to where shall I look through more to get the information.

So, essentially, as shown in the screenshot below, what I am looking for is getting the string "Ashwin" from the window title, or any other place where pidgin stores it. Alternately, if we have some global variable set to the username with whom we are having a conversation, that will also work for me.

[image: Screenshot of the Conversation Window]

Comment: What is your plugin doing? What context are you trying to get this in? Do you already have a `PurpleConversation` or `PidginConversation` or anything?